# modules are missing /sys/module/*/parameters directories, how to enable them?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Many of my modules are missing /sys/module/*/parameters directory and I can't check the module loaded parameters.

```
# printf "%s\n" /sys/module/*/parameters | wc -l
125
# lsmod | wc -l
151
# comm -13 <(printf "%s\n" /sys/module/*/parameters | xargs dirname | xargs basename -a | sort) <(lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | sort) | fmt
Module aesni_intel at24 blake2b_generic bpf_preload btbcm btintel
btmtk btrfs btrtl crc16 crc32_pclmul crc32c_generic crc32c_intel
crct10dif_pclmul cryptd crypto_simd crypto_user dummy ecdh_generic fat
gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel i2c_smbus iTCO_vendor_support iTCO_wdt
intel_cstate intel_pmc_bxt intel_rapl_common intel_rapl_msr intel_uncore
ip6_tables ip6t_REJECT ip6table_filter ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat
ip6table_raw ip_tables ipt_REJECT iptable_filter iptable_mangle
iptable_nat iptable_raw irqbypass joydev ledtrig_audio libcrc32c lpc_ich
mac_hid mei mei_hdcp mei_me mei_pxp mei_wdt nf_conntrack_broadcast
nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack_pptp nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_log_syslog nf_nat nf_nat_amanda nf_nat_ftp nf_nat_h323 nf_nat_irc
nf_nat_pptp nf_nat_sip nf_nat_snmp_basic nf_nat_tftp nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv6 nfnetlink nfnetlink_log nvidia nvme_common parport
polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ppdev raid6_pq rapl sha512_ssse3
snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ts_kmp
tun uas vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vfat vmd x_tables xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas
xor xt_CT xt_LOG xt_NFLOG xt_addrtype xt_comment xt_conntrack xt_hashlimit
xt_mark xt_multiport xt_tcpudp
```

Most notably I was interested in:

```
# lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             77824  20
nvidia_modeset       1515520  40 nvidia_drm
nvidia_uvm           2891776  0
video                  69632  1 nvidia_modeset
nvidia              61472768  2179 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
# ls /sys/module/nvidia/parameters
ls: cannot access '/sys/module/nvidia/parameters': No such file or directory
```

But also dummy doesn't have parameters, which cmon, it's a dummy:

```
# modprobe dummy numdummies=12
# lsmod | grep dummy
dummy                  16384  0
root@leonidas /root
# ls /sys/module/dummy/parameters
ls: cannot access '/sys/module/dummy/parameters': No such file or directory
# ip a | grep dummy | wc -l
12
```

I found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774731 about also missing dummy/parameters directory.

How to enable that directory so that I can get kernel module parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for modules to have their parameters visible in `/sys/module/*/parameters`, the module needs to provide a `module_param_cb()` callback function for each parameter. Those functions will have to "know where to look" for the current setting of the respective parameter, so the `sysfs` filesystem driver can use them to figure out the parameters and their states on demand.

If the module uses the `module_param(name, type, perm)` or `module_param_named(name, value, type, perm)` macros to declare their parameters, the callback function is generated automatically unless `perm` is specified as 0.

The `dummy` module declares its module parameter like this:

```
module_param(numdummies, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(numdummies, "Number of dummy pseudo devices");
```

explicitly specifying the `perm` as 0, which makes the parameter not visible in sysfs.

The main `nvidia` module declares its own `NV_MODULE_PARAMETER(x)` and `NV_MODULE_STRING_PARAMETER(x)` macros (in `common/inc/nv-linux.h` within the NVidia driver package), which use `module_param()` with the `perm` parameter set to 0:

```
#define NV_MODULE_PARAMETER(x)          module_param(x, int, 0)
#define NV_MODULE_STRING_PARAMETER(x)   module_param(x, charp, 0)
```

Other modules in the driver package, like `nvidia_modeset`, `nvidia_drm` and `nvidia_uvm` do use `module_param()` in a more normal fashion, and those modules do have their parameters in `/sys/module/*/parameters` as expected.

Apparently, the `nvidia` module internally handles its parameters as something called "registry keys" (see `nvidia/nv-reg.h` in the driver package). Perhaps this is some kind of attempt to provide a cross-platform interface for NVidia driver parameters, that is at least in some sense similar between Windows and Linux?

Note also that the `nvidia` module provides its own `/proc/driver/nvidia/params` pseudo-file, which provides all the parameters in one virtual file.

So, in a nutshell:
I would recommend you to look at `/proc/driver/nvidia/params` instead and to see if it fits your needs. If not, and if you are willing to build a custom version of the NVidia driver, you might (at your own risk) try changing the definitions of the `NV_MODULE_PARAMETER()` and `NV_MODULE_STRING_PARAMETER()` macros to have a `perm` value other than 0, e.g.:

```
#define NV_MODULE_PARAMETER(x)          module_param(x, int, 0400)
#define NV_MODULE_STRING_PARAMETER(x)   module_param(x, charp, 0400)
```

to make all parameters declared this way readable using the `/sys/module/*/parameters` interface, by the root user only.

If it works, you might then send NVidia an enhancement request.

Comment: Amazing, that's great, amazing answer, thank you. Do you know is there an actual reason (memory usage?) that a module might _want_ to disable /sys/module/*/parameter access, or is this just rather a developer oversight that the last argument is `0` instead of `0400`?

Comment: In a general case, I suppose the kernel developers have made it *possible* to disable access for a reason, e.g. in case a particular module parameter includes an encryption secret or something like that. In these specific cases of the `dummy` and `nvidia` modules, you would have to ask the respective module maintainers for their design choices.